# MLT (More Like This) elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use elasticsearch MLT (More Like This) query.

Only one doc in store:

```
{
        "_index": "monitors",
        "_type": "monitor",
        "_id": "AVTnvJ8SancUpEdFLMiq",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ProcessGroup": "test",
          "ProcessName": "test",
          "OpName": "test",
          "Domain": "test",
          "LogLevel": "Info",
          "StartDateTime": "2016-05-04 04:46:47",
          "EndDateTime": "2016-05-04 04:47:47",
          "MessageDateTime": "2016-05-04 04:46:47",
          "ApplicationCode": "test",
          "Status": "10",
        }
}
```

Query:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this" : {
        "fields" : ["ProcessName"],
        "like" : "test",
        "min_term_freq" : 1,
        "max_query_terms" : 12
    }
  }
}
```

`ProcessName` is a not analyzed field.
I was expected to get this document as a response, but instead i got nada:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Why is that ?

***Another question:***

Suppose I have search engines docs, and I search for "stph". I expect to get "Stephan Curry" suggestion because it's commonly searched. Fuzzy search doesn't fit because distance is greater than 2, so does using MLT query is a good option for this scenario ?